# operator+ confusion (pointer vs. reference)

Tags: c++, xcode

Even after years C++ is confusing the hell out of me..
My class implements

```
virtual CStatCounter& operator= (CStatCounter const& inSC);
```

and

```
virtual CStatCounter operator+(const CStatCounter& rhs);
```

And I'm keeping a

```
vector<CStatCounter*> mStatistics
```

somewhere else. Now all I'm trying to do is accumulate all values.
After being laughed at by std::accumulate I've switched to a simple loop rolled on my own, still no luck:

```
CStatCounter *iniCounter = new CStatCounter(0);
BOOST_FOREACH (CStatCounter *counter, mStatistics)
{
   iniCounter = iniCounter+counter;
}
```

The compiler (Xcode 4.2/clang) complains about

```
Invalid operands to binary expression ('CStatCounter *' and 'CStatCounter *')
```

I can change the loop body to counter+counter and it still fails with the same error message.

Shouldn't it be smart enough to implicitly convert between references and pointers?
Am I missing something trivial here?

Comment: I'm confused as to why your plus operator returns a `bool` and not a `CStatCounter`

Comment: Hi Jay, not an answer to your question but if you were using boost::ptr_vector instead of a std::vector of pointers your would be iterating over references instead of pointers. Would have avoided this situation.

Comment: Because.. I'M TOO STUPID TO COPY&PASTE!!!! D'OH! Thanks for that.    Should be returning a    CStatCounter of course...

Comment: @Jay: please correct the question then with the real code?

Comment: Sorry, I was in fact copying the real code, BUT in the real code copied operator+ from operator> w/o fixing the return value..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Shouldn't it be smart enough to implicitly convert between references
>   and pointers?

It could, but that wouldn't be C++, would it?  When you can overload operators for every conceivable combination of operands, it's really not safe to make such assumptions.

> Am I missing something trivial here?

Dereferencing:

```
*iniCounter = *iniCounter + *counter;
```

By the way, you can still use std::accumulate, you just need a custom binary operation, like this:

```
CStatCounter MyAddFunc(const CStatCounter & lhs, const CStatCounter * rhsp)
{
    return lhs + *rhsp;
}

*iniCounter = std::accumulate(mStatistics.begin(), mStatistics.end(),
                              *iniCounter, MyAddFunc);
```

Comment: *Sigh* And I was really hoping for the compiler-can-be-smart-if-you-do-... answer ;-)

Answer (score 3):

How about `*iniCounter = *iniCounter + *counter;`?

On a side note, are you sure all those pointers and virtuals are really necessary?

Comment: It's the base class for a bunch of derived classes keeping the actual, concrete statistics!

Comment: As far as the counters go - hate STL copying my stuff around all the time. In this trivial scenario (one int or double member per instance) probably nothing to worry about, though..

Comment: @antlersoft: Why on earth would `operator+` return a `bool`?

Comment: @FredOverflow -- The question as written had it returning a bool; however he's since commented that that was a typo

Comment: My bad - copy and paste error when creating the class.. of course it should create CStatCounter

Answer (score 2):

There is no implicit conversion here.

You will have to either provide exact overloads which you make use of.

```
virtual bool operator+(const CStatCounter* rhs);
virtual CStatCounter& operator= (CStatCounter const* inSC);
```

or modify your code to match the overloads you provided.

```
*iniCounter = *iniCounter + *counter;
```

Comment: Sometimes I hate C++. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Jay: For me Its usually a love hate relationship most of the times :)